# Why the pug page not work in my nodejs code

Tags: node.js, rendering

I want to show the images and videos related to each Id of the saved files(on my server) on the 'media.pug' page.

I am using the following codes, but it does not render the desired media.pug page.

My form submit:

```
 form(action="/medias/" + some_id method="GET")
    input(type="submit" value="Photo / Image")
```

some_id is for example 54.
The router:

```
router.get("/medias/:some_id" , InfoCtrl.apiMedias);
```

And in the InfoCtrl controller:

```
static async apiMedias(req, res, next) {
     try {
          const Id= req.params.some_id;
          const imagesPath = path.join(__dirname, `../public/media/${Id}/image`);
          const videosPath = path.join(__dirname, `../public/media/${Id}/video`);
          let images = [];
          let videos = [];

          function foo (folder, enconding)  {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    fs.readdir(folder,enconding, function(err, filenames){
                        if (err) 
                            reject(err); 
                        else 
                            resolve(filenames);    
                    });
                });
            };

            foo(imagesPath).then((value)=>{
                 images= value;
            }).then(foo(videosPath).then((value)=>{
                     videos= value;
            }).then((value)=>{
                    var model =  {"phoneId": phoneId, "images": images , "videos": videos};
                    console.log(model);
                    res.render("media", {
                        "model": model,
                    });
            }));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

What is wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was not any problem with my above code, but there was a problem with my layout page which the reference to the style and other scripts was wrong so they were pending when was loading.
before editing it was like this:

```
link(href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet")
```

But I canged to:

```
link(href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet")
```

and it works now.